# Why GG Cloud Vision gives different outcomes (on different platforms) on the same image

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

I'm basically writing an Android app that detects object's color using GG Cloud Vision. However, the outcomes I saw when I tried on the website is different when I actually used it on my app.

I tested the attached picture on this [website](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/detecting-properties). And it shows that the dominant color is [49,49,49] (black) with a 0.47 score. However, when I actually deployed Cloud Vision into Android Studio and tried with the same picture, this time, I get different dominant color, with RGB 250,250,250. I'm so confused. My expectation is it would returns the black color as it did in the website. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8gfWB.png)

Comment: Which language are you using? I suppose you are using the Cloud Vision client library for some language

Comment: I'm using Java in Android Studio.

Comment: May you share how you are creating your request?